# How invoke code after await Promise.all.then in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, promise, es6-promise

Consider example:

**js**

```
"use strict";

const input = [
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru"
];
const createPhantomPool = require('phantom-pool');
(async function() {
    console.log("start");
    const pool = createPhantomPool({max: input.length*2, min: input.length*2});
    let promises = [];
    input.forEach(url => promises.push(pool.use(async (instance) => {
        instance.createPage()
            .then(page => {
                return page.open(url);
            }).then(() => console.log("load finished"))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    })));
    await (Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log("after then")));
    console.log("end");
}());
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.68.0",
  "es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
  "log4js": "^1.1.1",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
  "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
  "webpage": "^0.3.0"
```

I expecte that all promised will be finished and only after that `console.log("after then")` is called. But this example gives me the following output:

```
start
after then
end
load finished
load finished
load finished
load finished
load finished
```

Why `after then` is printed before `load finished`???

Comment: Not familiar with "phantom-pool", but it looks like you're not returning the promise from `instance.createPage()`...have been bitten by this many a time...go TypeScript!

Comment: I do not think so, was taken `instance.createPage()` from [this](https://github.com/binded/phantom-pool) and should return a `Promise`.

Comment: Yes but you aren't returning that promise, ie you do not have `return instance.createPage()`. If you want the arrow function to auto return, then you need to remove the surrounding curly braces `{}`

Comment: Yeah, but there's a difference..they are `awaiting` promises with in the `use` handler, thus, it won't return until they are done. You aren't. You should `return` or `await` `instance.createPage()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the promise in `pool.use` from `instance.createPage()`

```
"use strict";

const input = [
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru",
    "https://www.google.ru"
];
const createPhantomPool = require('phantom-pool');
(async function() {
    console.log("start");
    const pool = createPhantomPool({max: input.length*2, min: input.length*2});
    let promises = [];
    input.forEach(url => promises.push(pool.use(async (instance) => {
        await instance.createPage()
            .then(page => {
                return page.open(url);
            }).then(() => console.log("load finished"))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    })));
    await (Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log("after then")));
    console.log("end");
}());
```

This has been tested. What's happening is `pool.use` isn't waiting for the promise from `instance.createPage()` to resolve. You either have to `return` the promise, or `await` it. You already have it's wrapper as an `async` function, so might as well be consistent and `await` it.